# Index an entity with many collections

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I have a `User` entity that I am looking to index.  I'm currently looking at Hibernate-Search and ran across an issue with performance.

My POJO has a lot of `Collections` within it.  I am not looking to populate these fields however.  Is anyone aware of a way to do this using the `MassIndexer'?

Here's a snippet of my POJO

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class User {
   @Id
   private long id;

   @Field
   private List<Address> addresses;   // Address.street is what I am looking for

   @Field
   private String firstName;

   @Field
   private String lastName;

   private List<AKA> akas;

   private List<Wife> wives;

   ...

}
```

In this example, I am looking to avoid indexing anything not marked with `@Field`, however when I run the `MassIndexer`, I am seeing all the other `Collection`s getting loaded.

Currently, here's how I'm reindexing

```
fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

Any idea's on how to avoid this to speed up my indexing time?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Search will only "navigate" to the relations it needs to build the index, so it will only trigger loading of those lazy collections which are necessary.

If Hibernate is loading the other collections, it is probably caused by the fact that these collections are not mapped as lazy associations.
Make sure all relations are marked as lazy, that is a good practice anyway as you can make any lazy relation eager at runtime - for example by using a "fetch load" instruction in your HQL but you can't do the opposite.

In your specific case, is probably caused by the way you're mapping collections: using `List` without an ordering column will be treated as a bag, which is very inefficient.